# String value as Object key

Tags: java, android, json, gson, key-value

Let's say I've got `String A = "A";` and `String B = "B";` and I want to use these values as keys in a json object.

```
{
    "A":"string1",
    "B":"string2"
}
```

Now in another time and space, I'd like to get these `String` values from the `Json Object`. I'd have to get the value for "A" and "B". We can just use A and B when making this json object and reuse them when getting the values.

**However**, I'm trying to make a `Json Object` from an actual `Object`. I'm using `Gson` to achieve this. How can I use A and B as keys when making the object?

Comment: Can you show us your current code?

Comment: You can create a `Map<String,String>` with `A` and `B` as key and serialize it using GSON. to get `A` and `B` back, you can deserialize it to Map and get the keys

Answer (score 1):

Using [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson) you can parse the JSON into a `Map` as

```
String json = "{\n" +
        "\"A\":\"string1\",\n" +
        "\"B\":\"string2\"\n" +
    "}";

Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();

Map<String, String> map = gson.fromJson(json, type);

System.out.println(map.get("A")); // string1
System.out.println(map.get("B")); // string2
```

Alternatively, if you want to wrap the keys in an already existing object

```
String json = "{ pairs : {\n" +
        "\"A\":\"string1\",\n" +
        "\"B\":\"string2\"\n" +
    "} }";

Gson gson = new Gson();

JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);

System.out.println(jsonObject.getPairs().get("A")); // string1
System.out.println(jsonObject.getPairs().get("B")); // string2
```

where the `JsonObject` could look like

```
class JsonObject {
    private Map<String, String> pairs;

    public Map<String, String> getPairs() {
        return pairs;
    }
}
```